# Warning - React

Tags: reactjs, ionic2, react-proptypes

I'm having a little problem with a warning in my Ionic 2 code:

```
Warning: Accessing PropTypes via the main React package is deprecated. Use the prop-types package from npm instead.
```

I'm not using anything about React or proptypes, but I'm getting the message describe before.

My package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
 "@angular/common": "2.4.8",
 "@angular/compiler": "2.4.8",
 "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.4.8",
 "@angular/core": "2.4.8",
 "@angular/forms": "2.4.8",
 "@angular/http": "2.4.8",
 "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.8",
 "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.8",
 "@angular/platform-server": "2.4.8",
 "@auth0/cordova": "^0.1.0",
 "@ionic-native/calendar": "^3.6.1",
 "@ionic-native/camera": "^3.12.1",
 "@ionic-native/core": "^3.10.3",
 "@ionic-native/date-picker": "^3.10.3",
 "@ionic/app-scripts": "0.0.38",
 "@ionic/storage": "2.0.0",
 "angular2-jwt": "0.1.27",
 "auth0-js": "^7.4.0",
 "auth0-lock": "10.13.0",
 "chart.js": "^2.6.0",
 "firebase": "^3.9.0",
 "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
 "intl": "^1.2.5",
 "ion2-calendar": "^1.0.7",
 "ionic-angular": "2.2.0",
 "ionic-native": "2.4.1",
 "ionicons": "3.0.0",
 "moment": "^2.18.1",
 "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^1.1.0",
 "rxjs": "5.0.1",
 "sw-toolbox": "3.4.0",
 "xml2js": "^0.4.17",
 "zone.js": "0.7.2"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
"@ionic/app-scripts": "1.1.4",
"typescript": "2.0.9"
},
"cordovaPlugins": [
"cordova-plugin-device",
"cordova-plugin-console",
"cordova-plugin-whitelist",
"cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
"cordova-plugin-statusbar",
"ionic-plugin-keyboard"
 ],
"cordovaPlatforms": [
"ios",
{
  "platform": "ios",
  "version": "",
  "locator": "ios"
}
]
```

I have check line by line my code and nothing seems to be calling proptype or react.

I will appreciate any help.

Best Regards

Comment: Try `npm ls react` to see which dependence requires react.

Comment: Thanks @YuryTarabanko I found it, auth0-lock had the dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found which library had the dependency with React, our friendly "auth0-lock": "10.13.0" has it. 
Solution: Upgrade to version 10.18.0 and message is gone forever and ever.

Thanks to @YuryTarabanko for the approach.

Regards.

Answer (score -1):

Just because you're not using PropTypes doesn't mean some other component that you've pulled in as a dependency isn't. And warnings will be displayed for those packages as well. If you want details about the warning specifically, you can [read about it here](https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/dont-call-proptypes.html).

Comment: I've already checked that documentation, but it doesn't help me much.

Thanks anyway.